Characterizing groups where every core-free subgroup is trivial
I am interested in characterizing all of the (finite) groups, $G$, where the only core-free subgroup of $G$ is the trivial group. Recall that a subgroup, $H\subset G$, is called core-free if $H$ contains no non-trivial normal subgroups of $G$. For instance here is the subgroup lattice for $D_{18}$ produced via GAP:

The subgroups in boxes are normal and therefore not core-free (except the trivial subgroup). The 4-x subgroups are not normal, but they contain a non-trivial normal subgroup, namely the 3 subgroup. Hence the 4-x subgroups are not core-free. Therefore the only core-free subgroups of $D_{18}$ are the 2-x subgroups and, of course, the trivial subgroup itself.
As I noted above, I am interested in cases where the only core-free subgroup of $G$ is the trivial group.
Example 1: Every subgroup, $H\subset G$, of an abelian group, $G$, is also a normal subgroup, $H\lhd G$. Normal subgroups cannot be core-free unless we have $H=1$.
Example 2: The above proof actually applies for some non-abelian groups. Namely, it holds for all Dedekind groups, $G$. N.B.: Non-abelian Dedekind groups are called Hamiltonian.
I have also found several more non-Dedekind examples by typing up some basic GAP code. My question is: Is there any nice characterization of these non-Dedekind examples? In a response to a previous question I was told that for $p$-groups with $p>2$ this condition is equivalent to the group being p-central.
To finish: I will now list all of the non-Dedekind examples with order less than 30. I will also show a couple of their subgroup lattices.
Gap ID: (12,1)     $\quad Q_{12}=Z_3\rtimes Z_4$

Gap ID: (16,4)     $\quad Z_4\rtimes Z_4$

Gap ID: (16,9)     $\quad Q_{16}$
Gap ID: (20,1)     $\quad Q_{20}$
Gap ID: (24,1)     $\quad Z_3\rtimes Z_8$
Gap ID: (24,4)     $\quad Z_3\rtimes Q_8$
Gap ID: (24,7)     $\quad Q_{12}\times Z_2$
Gap ID: (28,1)     $\quad Z_7\rtimes Z_4$
Are these always (semi-)products of Q's and Z's?
[Edit: I have found a similar question asked here].
